# The command started in the QProcess does not return a response on linux

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qprocess

I'm tryin get loaction of `node` package. Using `QProcess` to execute commang `which node`:

```
QProcess process;
process.start("/usr/bin/which", QStringList() << tr("node"));
process.waitForFinished(-1);
response = process.readAllStandardOutput();
qDebug() << response;
```

But in debug I got `""`.

Project located on [GitHub](https://github.com/Dissfall/nodeGator/blob/develop). Problem in https://github.com/Dissfall/nodeGator/blob/develop/mainwindow.cpp

Comment: Why on earth are you using `tr()` for the "node" argument?

Comment: Try reading [`stderr`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#readAllStandardError) as well -- in case `node` isn't found.

Comment: @JesperJuhl , I agree. This is not necessary here. But this does not solve the problem))

Comment: @G.M. already did it. Also returns `""`

Comment: Check for errors.  What does `/usr/bin/which node` output when run at a command prompt?

Comment: @G.M. in `bash` it returns `/home/george/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/bin/node`. This is what I need to get in `Qt`

Comment: @G.M. I add project on GitHub. Proble in [this](https://github.com/Dissfall/nodeGator/blob/develop/mainwindow.cpp) file. I added a comment. Maybe it will be helpful

Answer (score 1):

It may depend under what shell is running your app in QtCreator and under what one in terminal (bash/sh/csh etc.). The PATH variable may differ;

1. u can check process.exitCode() i.e. when 'which' doesn't find tool, it return 1; otherwise 0
2. may be, try to list the env. with:

   ```
   qDebug() << "env:" << QProcessEnvironment::systemEnvironment().toStringList();
   ```

You can see actual settings in QtCreator -> Projects -> ur KIT -> Run and "Run Environment" details. There is an option to set in which environment the app is running: build/system/clear - try change.

Comment: Thanks for answer. First way is worked. It's wery helpfull for me. I checked environment variables. In this moment `SHELL=/bin/bash`.

Comment: This turned out to be really valuable. The app was not working from Qt-Creator, but it was working if I execute the binary independently from the build folder. Thanks.